# LINQ with specific words not working

Tags: c#, linq

UPDATE:  Here is the exact code I'm using instead of giving a basic example.

```
query = context.GetQueryable<SearchCustomers>() // This is a huge list of customers

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(company))
                        query = query.Where(x => x.CompanyName.Contains(company));
```

The company name is Mike and Joe Repair Shop

If i search for just "Mike" it returns Mike and Joe Repair Shop as expected.  If i search for "Mike and Joe Repair Shop" it returns Null.  If i search for "Joe Repair Shop" it returns the expected Mike and Joe Repair Shop.

I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that the word "and" is in the string.

I'm having an issue where if the word a query is looking for contains the word "and" it fails.  Here is the situation:

```
var word = "Cats and Dogs"

query = word.contains("Cats and Dogs")
return query
//This returns NULL

if i do query = word.contains("Cat")
return query
//This returns Cat and Dog

if i do query = word.contains("Cat And")
return query
//This returns Cat and Dog
```

Do I need to escape the "and" word?

Comment: There is no LINQ here, `Contains` is an instance method defined on `String` class, and that's what's being called here.

Comment: Are  you sure you have `var word = "Cats and Dogs"` and not `var word = "Cat and Dog"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string.Contains()` method is only for matching against substrings of a string. As such it is not a reserved keyword when using the `Contains()` method. I tried a two different ways to test your assertion about the `and`:

```
List<string> phrases = new List<string>() {"Cats and Dogs", "Cats and Bats", "Dogs and Trees"};
IEnumerable<string> f = phrases.Where<string>(x =>x.Contains("Cats and Dogs"));
System.Console.WriteLine(f.FirstOrDefault());
> Cats and Dogs
```

Again:

```
List<string> phrases = new List<string>() {"Cats and Dogs", "Cats and Bats", "Dogs and Trees"};
IEnumerable<string> g = from phrase in phrases where phrase.Contains("Cats and Dogs") select phrase;
System.Console.WriteLine(g.FirstOrDefault())
> Cats and Dogs
```

My best guess is that there are unicode spaces in the original `CompanyName` which is not matching with `Contains()` against a string with ascii white space.

For example:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Cats and Dogs");
> Cats and Dogs
System.Console.WriteLine("Cats and\u2000Dogs");
> Cats and Dogs
System.Console.WriteLine("Cats and\u2000Dogs".Contains("Cats and Dogs"));
> False
```

Comment: I think you on to something with Unicode spaces.  I will have to check if that is the case.